# rJava: using java/lang/Vector with a certain template class

Tags: r, vector, rjava

I'm currently programming an R-script which uses a java .jar that makes use of the java/lang/Vector class, which in this case uses a class in a method that is not native. In java source code:

```
public static Vector<ClassName> methodname(String param)
```

I found nothing in the documentation of rJava on how to handle a template class like vector and what to write when using jcall or any other method.
I'm currently trying to do something like this:

```
v <- .jnew("java/util/Vector")
b <- .jcall(v, returnSig = "Ljava/util/Vector", method = "methodname",param)
```

but R obviously throws an exception:

```
method methodname with signature (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Vector not found
```

How do I work the template class into this command? Or for that matter, how do I create a vector of a certain class in the first place? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rJava` does not know java generics, there is no syntax that will create a `Vector` of a given type. You can only create `Vector`s of `Object`s.

Why are you sticking with the old `.jcall` api when you can use the `J` system, which lets you use java objects much more nicely:

```
> v <- new( J("java.util.Vector") )
> v$add( 1:10 )
[1] TRUE
> v$size()
[1] 1
# code completion
> v$
v$add(                 v$getClass()           v$removeElement(
v$addAll(              v$hashCode()           v$removeElementAt(
v$addElement(          v$indexOf(             v$retainAll(
v$capacity()           v$insertElementAt(     v$set(
v$clear()              v$isEmpty()            v$setElementAt(
v$clone()              v$iterator()           v$setSize(
v$contains(            v$lastElement()        v$size()
v$containsAll(         v$lastIndexOf(         v$subList(
v$copyInto(            v$listIterator(        v$toArray(
v$elementAt(           v$listIterator()       v$toArray()
v$elements()           v$notify()             v$toString()
v$ensureCapacity(      v$notifyAll()          v$trimToSize()
v$equals(              v$remove(              v$wait(
v$firstElement()       v$removeAll(           v$wait()
v$get(                 v$removeAllElements()
```

Comment: Thank you, doing it with J really is much easier.